MetadataService mock class for retrieving RecordTypes from Profiles/PermissionSets
Let's say there is a need to compose apex test class for classes that use MetadataService.
 MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MigrationToolsHelper.getMdAPIService();
    MetadataService.PermissionSet permissionSet = (MetadataService.PermissionSet)
        service.readMetadata('PermissionSet',
             new String[]{'SomePermset'})
        .getRecords()[0];

    Map<String, MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility> existingRTs = 
        new Map<String, MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility>();
    if(permissionSet.recordTypeVisibilities != null) {
        for(MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility rt : permissionSet.recordTypeVisibilities) {
            existingRTs.put(rt.recordType, rt);
        }
    } 
    for(MetadataService.PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility rt : sourceRecordTypes) {
        if(existingRTs.get(rt.recordType) == null) {
            existingRTs.put(rt.recordType, rt);
        }
    }
    permissionSet.recordTypeVisibilities = existingRTS.values();
    List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results = service.upsertMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { permissionSet });

i just started with
    @isTest
public  class MigrationToolsMetadataMock  implements WebServiceMock {
        public void doInvoke(
            Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
            String endpoint, String soapAction, String requestName,
            String responseNS, String responseName, String responseType) {
                
            if(request instanceof MetadataService.readMetadata_element)
                response.put('response_x', new MetadataService.readMetadataResponse_element());
            } else if(request instanceof MetadataService.upsertMetadata_element) {
                response.put('response_x', new MetadataService.upsertMetadataResponse_element());
            }
        
}

but really have no clear idea how to provide some results both for read and upsert in my test class.

Here is an example for CustomObject; you'll need to adapt it for PermissionSetRecordTypeVisibility  but basically you have to mock the structure that the MetadataService would return in a non-test context.  It has been a while since I've done this but I found it helpful to execute the md-api code and use system.debug to understand the structure returned (this will guide your mocking)
